# Convert to .swf programmatically in iOS using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, flash

Can we convert any file to .swf files programmatically in iOS with Objective-C using any native or external framework?

Comment: Any file? What is a database file or Zip file supposed to look like when it's converted to SWF?

Comment: Thanks for your response,it can be any database file.Also could you tell what are all types can be converted to .swf files programatically

Comment: Sorry, I think you didn't quite understand my question. I cannot image what a database file converted to SWF should look like. I makes no sense to me. Can you better explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: lets assume we have data in database or some excel sheets,using them we will generate charts and graphs in ipad dashboard application,now we need a way to convert the data  to .swf files,so we need the  formats of intermediate files(e.g jpeg) we need to generate which can be converted to .swf files programmatically using objective C